# Read from CSV file with Java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to learn Java... 
And I am facing a (simple) problem.

==> I have a csv file:

```
This road;123;That place
Another road;456;Another place
```

==> I have some java code:

```
package tijdelijk;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ReadFromCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String CSVadres = "src/tijdelijk/ReadFromCSV.csv";
        try (Scanner adresScanner = new Scanner(new File(CSVadres))) {
            adresScanner.useDelimiter(";");
            while (adresScanner.hasNext()) {
                String adresIter = adresScanner.next();
                int nummerIter = Integer.parseInt(adresScanner.next());
                String plaatsIter = adresScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("straat\t\t" + adresIter);
                System.out.println("huisnummer\t" + nummerIter);
                System.out.println("plaats\t\t" + plaatsIter);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReadFromCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

==> I have output:

```
run:
straat      This road
huisnummer  123
plaats      ;That place

straat      Another road
huisnummer  456
plaats      ;Another place

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

==> I have a problem....

Why do I get the semicolon in teh "plaats" field?
How should I write my code to fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Kind regards from The Netherlands,
Pierre

Comment: `nextLine()` doesn't use delimiters.

Comment: Ok, I understand this, sounds logical, but how to solve the problem?

Comment: I would just read the whole line and then use `String::split`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the world of Java. I suggest you use a library for CSV parsing (even though csv is mostly simple enough to do a "`scanner.next().split(";")`" - I suggest the Apache Commons CSVParser

Edit: Found here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html

Comment: I will look at IT when I get at my computer later.

Answer (score 0):

The `Scanner#useDelimiter` method takes a regex string as input. So you could use it by defining two delimiters like the following

```
adresScanner.useDelimiter(";|\n");
```

The first one will be your inline delimiter and the second one is the newline delimiter.

Then, you don't need to use `nextLine()` anymore but only `next()`

Comment: I tried that, but if I remenber correctly, the \n did not work properly.

Comment: @Pierre On which OS are you working? Try the following maybe `";|\r\n"`. It works fine on `IdeOne` : https://ideone.com/DGkMAF

Comment: That is weird.
I just tested it in my program and it works.
Suppose I did something wrong thie morning.

You asked about the OS I am working on.....
Should Java not be OS indepedent?

Comment: @Pierre Indeed, but the delimiters are OS-specific I believe. So the file you read from can be different written on Windows or on Linux

Comment: is that what they call computer logic???

Thanks for your reply.

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the scanner, you can read the entire line into a string and then split that string based on the semicolon and put the split string into an array:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String CSVadres = "C:/LCC Lev 4/test.csv";
        try (Scanner adresScanner = new Scanner(new File(CSVadres))) {
            while (adresScanner.hasNext()) {
                String fullAddress = adresScanner.nextLine();
                String [] addFields = fullAddress.split(";");
                String adresIter = addFields[0];
                String nummerIter = addFields[1];
                String plaatsIter = addFields[2];
                System.out.println("straat\t\t" + adresIter);
                System.out.println("huisnummer\t" + nummerIter);
                System.out.println("plaats\t\t" + plaatsIter);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it and (of course) it works.
Looks like a lot of work....
Isn't there an easier way?